# How to display the characters upto a specific index of a String using String function?

Tags: java, string

I have my string defined as

> text1:text2:text3:text4:text5

I want to get output as

> text1:text2:text3

using String methods.

I have tried using `lastIndexOf`, then `substring` and then again `lastIndexOf`.
I want to avoid these three steps with calling `lastIndexOf` two times.
Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Would you be able to explain your question further? It's not clear what the problem is you are trying to solve, because the example you have given is too abstract and not specific enough for people to provide a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression could be used to identify the correct part of the string:

```
private static Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("([^:]*:){2}[^:]*(?=:|$)");

public static String find(String input) {
    Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(input);
    return m.find() ? m.group() : null;
}
```

Alternatively do not use `substring` between every call of `lastIndexOf`, but use the version of `lastIndexOf` that restricts the index range:

```
public static String find(String input, int colonCount) {
    int lastIndex = input.length();
    while (colonCount > 0) {
        lastIndex = input.lastIndexOf(':', lastIndex-1);
        colonCount--;
    }
    return lastIndex >= 0 ? input.substring(0, lastIndex) : null;
}
```

Note that here `colonCount` is the number of `:` that are left out of the string.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by running a loop to iterate over the characters of the string from index = `0` to index = `lastIndexOf('3')`. Here's the code:

```
String s = "text1:text2:text3:text4:text5";
for(int i = 0; i < = s.lastIndexOf('3'); i++)
    System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
```

This gives you the required output.

**OUTPUT**:

```
text1:text2:text3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Java `split()`-method:

```
String string = "text1:text2:text3:text4:text5";
String[] text = string.split(":");
String text1 = text[0]; 
String text2 = text[1];
String text3 = text[2];
```

And then generate the output directly or with a for-loop:

```
// directly
System.out.println(text1 + ":" + text2 + ":" + text3);

// for-loop. Just enter, how many elements you want to display. 
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    System.out.println(text[i] + " ");
}
```

**Output:**

```
text1 text2 text3
```

The advantage of using this method is, that your input and output can be a bit more complex, because you have power over the order in which the words can be printed.

**Example:**

Consider Master Yoda.

He has a strange way of talking and often mixes up the sentence structure. When he introduces himself, he says the (incorrect!) senctence: "Master Yoda my name is".

Now, you want to create an universal translator, that - of course - fixes those mistakes while translating from one species to another.

You take in the input-string and "divide" it into its parts:

```
String string = "Master:Yoda:my:name:is"
String[] text = string.split(":");
String jediTitle = text[0];
String lastName = text[1]; 
String posessivePronoun = text[2];
String noun = text[3];
String linkingVerb = text[4];
```

The array "text" now contains the sentence in the order that you put it in. Now your translator can analyze the structure and correct it:

```
String correctSentenceStructure = posessivePronoun + " " + noun + " "  + linkingVerb + " "  + jediTitle + " " + lastName;    
System.out.println(correctSentenceStructure);
```

**Output:**

```
"My name is Master Yoda"
```

A working translator might be another step towards piece in the galaxy.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
String test = "text1:text2:text3:text4:text5";
String splitted = text.split(":")
String result = "";
for (int i = 0; i <3; i++) {
    result += splitted[i] + ":"
}
result = result.substring(0, result.length() -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maby try this one-line `s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf('3')+1);`

Complete example:

```
package testing.project;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "text1:text2:text3:text4:text5";
        System.out.println(s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf('3')+1));
    }
}
```

Output:

> text1:text2:text3